# Java: reading a string in a particular format

Tags: java, regex

I am not posting any code I am struck with. I am trying this in Java:

Issue:

I have words like:

```
,xxxx-1223
yyyyy,xxdd-345
$,xxxxr-7
sdsdsdd-18
```

so what ever format I have I should be able to read the last one:

```
xxxx-1223
xxdd-345
xxxxr-7
sdsdsdd-18
```

what so may be the words, all I need to to get the words as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String#lastIndexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) to find where the last comma occurs, and use [`String#substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) to get the rest of the string that follows.

```
String input = /* whatever */;
int lastComma = input.lastIndexOf(',');
String output = input.substring(lastComma + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] str=yourWord.split(",");
String output=str[str.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Regex: -

```
(\\w+-\\d+)$
```

Or this specific problem can simply be solved using [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) or [String.substring(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) methods